# If you see spam, don't just downvote - flag!

Tags: discussion, flagging, down-votes, spam

I recently saw a spam post that had a score of -6, but still hadn't been deleted. 3 spam flags knock it off the front page; 6 permanently delete it. ([What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work))

Anyone who has rep to downvote also has rep to flag - so please exercise that right!

Also, if you flag enough, you can get [shiny](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/65/deputy) [badges](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/marshal). ;D

Comment: Im not sure that post was spam... IAE it had 3 spam flags, 1 offensive flag, and 1 NAA flag when you posted this. Plus I think spam/offensive flags add a downvote to the score in addition to your own downvote.